# inconsistent formulaes in the list python

Tags: python, modal-logic

So the question relates to List of lists that store different propositional modal formulaes. I am capable of removing duplicates but I don't know how to find inconsistances. So for example:

**Initial List of lists:**

```
[[('not', ('box', 'p')), ('box', 'p'), ('not', 'q'), ('q'), ('diamond', 'r')],
 [('not', 'p'), 'q'], ['or', ('p', 'q')],
 ['not',('or', ('p', 'q'))],['r', 'q']]
```

The above sample list of lists has some problems I would like to simply find them and print out a message. For **example 1st list has box p and negated box
 p** I would like it to be detected. Also it has **not q and q**.

Similarly, **2nd list** has **not (p or q) and (p or q)**. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem, it could be something easy but I don't seem to be able to think of it.

Ideally, is it possible to mark a sublist as closed? Perhaps assign status closed?

Comment: Okay time for interrogation: What do you mean by 'I would like it to be detected'? Can you share your code that is not working so that we start somewhere on the same page as you? Why are you not using logic library like `sympy`?

Comment: So, I am translating string into tableau format which looks like the list above. By detecting, I simply want to print a message which will tell me that in list[1] there is p and not p formula and therefore this  list is inconsistent. I don't use sympy because it is not good enough for modal logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem I presented in the question. Works correctly, in case someone can improve it or make it shorter (or faster) please do post your proposition.

```
def inconsistent(psi):
for i in range(0,len(psi)):
    for j in range(0,len(psi[i])):
        main = psi[i]
        form = psi[i][j]
        if form[0] == 'not':
            notform = form[1]
            if form and notform in main:
                print "inconsistent: ", psi[i][j]
        else:
            notform = ('not', psi[i][j])
            if form and notform in main:
                print "inconsistent: ", psi[i][j]
            else:
                print "consistent: ", psi[i][j]


test = [[('not', ('box', 'p')), ('box', 'p'), ('not', 'q'), ('q'), ('diamond', 'r')], [('or', ('p', 'q')),('not',('or',('p','q')))],['not',('or', ('p', 'q'))],['r', 'q']]

inconsistent(test);
```